# Corona with Lua - Convert text to a formula

Tags: lua, coronasdk, string-conversion

Is there a way to convert "1 + 2 * 3" to 1 + 2 * 3 in a variable?  The numbers don't matter, I'm just trying to figure out how to get Lua to calculate a string as a number.  The tonumber() does not work for this.

Comment: It seems you can't use `loadstring`. A solution in pure Lua will depend on how complicated the expressions you intend to use are.

Comment: If you can use LPeg, try http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation#Lua.

Comment: I started reading into LPeg last night but didn't get a chance to try it out.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only simple operations, something like this may work:

```
function calculator(expression)
  expression = expression:gsub("%s+", "")
  while true do 
    local head, op1, op, op2, tail = expression:match("(.-)(%d+)([%*/])(%d+)(.*)")
    if not op then break end
    expression = head .. tostring(op == '*' and op1 * op2 or op1 / op2) .. tail
  end
  while true do 
    local head, op1, op, op2, tail = expression:match("(.-)(%d+)([%+%-])(%d+)(.*)")
    if not op then break end
    expression = head .. tostring(op == '+' and op1 + op2 or op1 - op2) .. tail
  end
  return tonumber(expression)
end

function calculator(expression)
  expression = expression:gsub("%s+","")
  local n
  repeat
    expression, n = expression:gsub("(%d+)([%*/])(%d+)",
      function(op1,op,op2) return tostring(op == '*' and op1 * op2 or op1 / op2) end, 1)
  until n == 0
  repeat
    expression, n = expression:gsub("(%d+)([%+%-])(%d+)",
      function(op1,op,op2) return tostring(op == '+' and op1 + op2 or op1 - op2) end, 1)
  until n == 0
  return tonumber(expression)
end

print(calculator('1 + 2') == 3)
print(calculator('1+2+3') == 6)
print(calculator('1+2-3') == 0)
print(calculator('1+2*3') == 7)
print(calculator('1+2*3/6') == 2)
print(calculator('1+4/2') == 3)
print(calculator('1+4*2/4/2') == 2)
print(calculator('a+b') == nil)
```

There are two `calculator` functions that do the same thing in slightly different ways: they collapse expressions until there is only a single number. `"1+2*3/6"` gets turned into `"1+6/6"`, then to `"1+1"`, and finally to `"2"`, which is returned as a number.

Comment: I added a tweak to the second implementation (`, 1` to `gsub`) to fix an issue with sequences of division or subtraction operations (to enforce left-to-right processing).